# How to use Amazon ALB port forwarding to run multiple services on a single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, aws-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have multiple services running on multiple ports on a single `AWS EC2` instances. I've been using two `ALBs` to run these services, but I'd like to combine them into a single ALB that forwards to the correct service based on the host name. One service is a node app running port 80 and the other is a flask app running on port 5001.

As of now, I have a target group setup as `mywebsite` for the node app on port 80, and `api-service` for my flask app on port 5001.

I added those target groups to an ALB, `my-alb`, and set up forwarding rules so that port 80 and 5001 will forward to port 443. On port 443 I set up forwarding rules so that if the host matches `api.*` it will forward to the target group `api-service` otherwise it will default to `my-website`.

I have also set up my alb as the alias for `api.mywebsite.com` and `www.mywebsite.com` on route 53 as well as setting up the certificate. All the health checks are passing for both my target groups.

Here's the issue:
`www.mywebsite.com` works properly. I get forwarded to the `https` version of the site and everything looks fine. When I try to use `api.mywebsite.com` it doesn't load and I get a 504 Bad Gateway error.

To summarize, here are the steps I've completed:

1. Setup two target groups for my services on `port 80 and 5001`
2. Added those two target groups to `ALB` and set routing rules to redirect to `port 443`
3. Set forwarding rules for route 443 to forward to the service on `port 5001` if the host matches `api.*` else route to the service on port 80.
4. Set the ALB as the alias for `api.mywebsite.com` and `www.mywebsite.com`in `route 53`.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Got it working.

I had configured my security group incorrectly. That is the step I was missing :D. Once I added port 5001 to the security group assigned to my ALB and EC2 it began to work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick advice for future troubleshooting. If you are getting timed out it is almost always SG, NACL or some other firewall blocking you.